# how to stop GPU NVIDIA calculation

Tags: nvidia, gpu

I'm currently into learning using NVIDIA for parallel calculation. Sometimes I run too many tasks in parallel and my computer stops responding (I use both CPU and GPU for calculations). So, I cannot break the process via `ps`, `kill`, etc., if I think it's taking too long. Is there a way to handle this situation except for a brute force restart?